# Passing javascript variable to php without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a 5x5 grid of div boxes (25 of them) and I am using jQuery UI to register when I drop a item in it. It will receive the title of the box it was dropped in and the name of the item, that part works.

I want to pass the title and name to PHP without refreshing the page (because then the items will reset). I get a "success!" but it seems like it doesn't pass the data.

**index.php**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "li img" ).draggable({ 
            snap: ".grid", 
            start: function (event, ui ) {
                item = $(this).attr('title');
            }
        });
        $( "li .grid" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                box = $(this).attr('title');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'index.php',
                    data: { box : 'box' },
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("success!");
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });        
</script>
```

**sessions.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
if(isset($_POST['box']))
{
   // store session data
   $_SESSION['box'] = $_POST['box'];
}
   //retrieve session data
   echo $_SESSION[box];
?>
```

How do I pass the title and name to PHP without refreshing the page?

Comment: @Dagon You're far out of line.

Comment: Thanks, you just gave me an idea, i was stuck on it like 3 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `url` and your `data` from this:

```
url: 'index.php',
data: { box : 'box' }
```

to this:

```
url: 'sessions.php',
data: { box : box }
```

Comment: i feel like a total idiot right now..  oh well thanks. while im at it how do i make it add instead of overwrite the data in session[box] ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're doing this...

```
box = $(this).attr('title');
```

I assume you want to pass that variable to the server. However, you're just passing the literal string `"box"`, not the variable `box`.

In your code, you've written this...

```
data: { box : 'box' },
```

which needs to be this, to pass the value in `box`:

```
data: { box : box },
```

---

As an aside, you've created a global variable `box`. Instead of `box = $(this).attr('title');`, you should use `var box = $(this).attr('title');` to create a variable local to the function.

Comment: i just tryed that, as before i get "success!" but it dosent get the data. i have <?php echo $_SESSION['box']; ?> in my index.php to se if the data is there but it dosen't write enything. and thanks for the "var" tip.

Comment: Verify the data is actually being sent. Check the value of `box` or open your browser's developer tools and inspect the AJAX request.

Comment: Felix found the stupidest error i have made ever. But big thanks to you for trying to help